# Background do botão não muda quando ele é clicado pela primeira vez. (Html5, CSS e JS puros)

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Bem, eu tenho uns botões que representam bolas de bingo, e quero que eles mudem de cor assim que são clicados, mas eles só mudam de cor a partir da segunda vez que são clicados. Tive que fazer uma gambiarra pra poder funcionar corretamente a adição ou remoção da bola sorteada do conjunto de bolas sorteadas. Como resolver para poder tirar a gambiarra?
Segue o código:

```
<style>
.botaoNumeros {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b00" onclick="selecionado(this)">00</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b01" onclick="selecionado(this)">01</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b02" onclick="selecionado(this)">02</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b03" onclick="selecionado(this)">03</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b04" onclick="selecionado(this)">04</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b05" onclick="selecionado(this)">05</button>
</body>

<script>
var bolas = [];

// TRANSFORMA O BOTÃO DE VERMELHO PRA VERDE, OU VICE-VERSA.
function selecionado(botao) {

    var bola = parseInt(botao.textContent);
    // Coloca o texto contido no botão (.textContent), que no caso é uma string entre 00 e 99, transformado em um inteiro pelo método parseInt().

    if (botao.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
        botao.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        botao.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    // Gambiarra feita por causa do problema da cor do background.
    if (botao.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
        if (bolas.indexOf(bola) > -1) {
            bolas.splice(bola, 1);
        }
    } else {
        if (bolas.indexOf(parseInt(botao.textContent)) == -1) {
            bolas.push(bola);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

(Creio que os IDs dos botões são desnecessários)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como a propriedade `.style.backgroundColor` inicialmente é **vazia**, significando que é `red`, basta colocar mais essa condição no `if`:

```
if (botao.style.backgroundColor === "red" || !botao.style.backgroundColor) {
                                                           ↑
                                                  verifica se é vazio
```

```js
// TRANSFORMA O BOTÃO DE VERMELHO PRA VERDE, OU VICE-VERSA.
function selecionado(botao) {

    var bola = parseInt(botao.textContent);
    // Coloca o texto contido no botão (.textContent), que no caso é uma string entre 00 e 99, transformado em um inteiro pelo método parseInt().
    if (botao.style.backgroundColor === "red" || !botao.style.backgroundColor) {
        botao.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        botao.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```css
.botaoNumeros {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b00" onclick="selecionado(this)">00</button>
<button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b01" onclick="selecionado(this)">01</button>
<button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b02" onclick="selecionado(this)">02</button>
<button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b03" onclick="selecionado(this)">03</button>
<button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b04" onclick="selecionado(this)">04</button>
<button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b05" onclick="selecionado(this)">05</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que pegar o `backgroundColor` utilizando o [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) já que esta propriedade esta em uma classe `.botaoNumeros` e não do atributo *style inline* `style='background-color:red'`.

Exemplo com style inline:

```js
function teste(btn){
    console.log("background-color:", btn.style.backgroundColor);
}
```

```css
button{ color: #FFF; }
.botao{ background-color: red; }
```

```html
<button style='background-color: blue;' onclick="teste(this);">Esse funciona, style inline</button><br/>
<button class="botao" onclick="teste(this);">Esse não funciona, style por class</button>
```

Aplicando `window.getComputedStyle` ao seu código.
**Note:** Ao usar o `getComputedStyle` ao invés de receber `red` você vai receber a cor em rgb `rgb(255, 0, 0)`:

```js
var bolas = [];

// TRANSFORMA O BOTÃO DE VERMELHO PRA VERDE, OU VICE-VERSA.
function selecionado(botao) {

    var bola = parseInt(botao.textContent);
    // Coloca o texto contido no botão (.textContent), que no caso é uma string entre 00 e 99, transformado em um inteiro pelo método parseInt().

    // modificado aki
    var btnStyle = window.getComputedStyle( botao );
    bgcolor = btnStyle.backgroundColor;
    console.log( bgcolor , botao.style.backgroundColor );

    if (bgcolor === "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
        botao.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        botao.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    // Gambiarra feita por causa do problema da cor do background.
    if (botao.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
        if (bolas.indexOf(bola) > -1) {
            bolas.splice(bola, 1);
        }
    } else {
        if (bolas.indexOf(parseInt(botao.textContent)) == -1) {
            bolas.push(bola);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.botaoNumeros {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b00" onclick="selecionado(this)">00</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b01" onclick="selecionado(this)">01</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b02" onclick="selecionado(this)">02</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b03" onclick="selecionado(this)">03</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b04" onclick="selecionado(this)">04</button>
    <button type="button" class="botaoNumeros" id="b05" onclick="selecionado(this)">05</button>
</body>
```